# WPDB getting a value from wp_capabilities

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to get a value from wpdb, but it does not seem to work, I've tried searching about it but had no luck, it is a custom role in WP. I apologize for a stupid question in advance.

I've got a meta_value which is:

```
a:1:{s:15:"nice_value";b:1;}
```

Using it like this does not work:

```
$count = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_value=a:1:{s:15:'nice_value';b:1;}");
```

I know that I'm doing something wrong but I can't figure out why it's not being brought out.
Thank you.

Comment: `WHERE meta_value = 'a:1:{s:15:''nice_value'';b:1;}'`? (quoting issue)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried quoting it like this and nothing changed, everything that comes after it is fine, I've tried entering a "normal looking" value like 'subscriber' and it worked with no problems.

Comment: Consider using a parameter instead.